# Accessing JSON array with a header in AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a php script that produces well formed JSON in this form; note that I have generated a 'header' to identify the category of data specific to my application (in this case, it's all the customers who are placed 'onhold':

```
{
  "onhold": [{
    "cust_id": "166999",
    "first_name": "Nathan",
    "last_name": "Hall" },

    {"cust_id": "166888",
    "first_name": "Susan",
    "last_name": "Gerson" }
  }]

}
```

I would then like to iterate through the array of these 'onhold' customers using AJAX.

I am trying to retrieve just one element in that JSON array just to understand the structure of the data object.  I would then write a simple loop to access all elements in the array.

I have tried the code below, but with no success (in the code below, the alert box never fires although I can see that the URL has loaded).  If successful, I would expect to see the first cust_num ('166999') appear in the alert box.

```
$.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 url: "php/payment_processing_test.php",
 dataType:"json",
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data[0].cust_id);
 }

});
```

Is there something odd in my JSON structure?

Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: You need to use `data.onhold[0].cust_id`. Note that your JSON describes an `Object` that contains a single property (`onhold`) whose value is the `Array` you want to iterate.

Comment: your first key is `onhold` so it should `data.onhold[0].cust_id`

Comment: That works - data.onhold[0].cust_id - thanks so much!